# Cache Eloquent query for response

Tags: laravel, caching, eloquent

In one of my applications I have a property that is needed throughout the app.

Multiple different parts of the application need access such as requests, local and global scopes but also commands.

I would like to "cache" this property for the duration of a request.

My current solution in my `Game` class looks like this:

```php
/**
 * Get current game set in the .env file.
 * @return Game
 */
public static function current()
{

    return Cache::remember('current_game', 1, function () {
        static $game = null;
        $id = config('app.current_game_id');
        if ($game === null || $game->id !== $id) {
            $game = Game::find($id);
        }
        return $game;
    });
}
```

I can successfully call this using `Game::current()` but this solutions feels "hacky" and it will stay cached over the course of multiple requests.

I tried placing a property on the current request object but this won't be usable for the commands and seems inaccessible in the blade views and the objects (without passing the `$request` variable.

Another example of its usage is described below:

```php
class Job extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('game_scope', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->whereHas('post', function ($query) {
                $query->where('game_id', Game::current()->id);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I do not believe I could easily access a request property in this boot method.

Another idea of mine would be to store the variable on a `Game` Facade but I failed to find any documentation on this practice.

Could you help me find a method of "caching" the `Game::current()` property accessible in most if not all of these cases without using a "hacky" method.

Comment: Why not keep it in a session and remove it when you don't need it anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Use the global session helper like this:

```
// Retrieve a piece of data from the session... 
$value = session('key'); 
// Store a piece of data in the session...
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

For configuration info and more options: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session